# JavaFx: can data binding (textfield) be used in production mode?

Tags: java, javafx

I use java 8.0.45. I have implemented my first javafx application (very simple) with data binding. However, biding from user input-> pojo seems to work with bugs. I've checked about 200 times. I entered new values in text fields and after that I checked model values. The same code, the same my behaviour. Sometimes everything works fine (in most cases - about 80-90%) sometimes model value!=textfield value. I've noticed the following. Data binding for some certain text field works,works and then at some point of time that binding stops working and all new values for this certain textfield are not passed to model. Nor exceptions. Nor any warnings. Nothing. Just binding doesn't work.

I have 4 textfiled which are created via fxml. Two for string model type. One for integer. One for bigdecimal. The problem happens to all these fields(sometimes to one, sometimes to several). As my number fields can have null values, I use for example PropertyObject but not IntegerProperty (people from openjfx advised so).

So is this JavaFx bug or what? P.S. I use felix osgi, weld cdi, and pax - I don't know if it matters...

My code is the following:

DTO - POJO Model

```
public class Task {

    private String name;

    private Integer order;

    private BigDecimal weight;

    private String comment;

    private final PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport;

    public Task() {
        this.propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        String pv = this.name ;
        this.name = name;
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("name", pv, name);
    }

    public Integer getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(Integer order) {
        Integer pv = this.order;
        this.order = order;
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("order", pv, this.order);
    }

    public BigDecimal getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(BigDecimal weight) {
        BigDecimal pv = this.weight;
        this.weight = weight;
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("weight", pv, weight);
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        String pv = this.comment;
        this.comment = comment;
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("comment", pv, this.comment);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

}
```

Adapter

```
public class TaskAdapter {

    private StringProperty nameProperty;

    private ObjectProperty<Integer> orderProperty;

    private ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> weightProperty;

    private StringProperty commentProperty;

      public TaskAdapter(Task task) {
        try {
            nameProperty=new JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder().bean(task).name("name").build();
            orderProperty=new JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder<Integer>().bean(task).name("order").build();
            weightProperty=new JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder<BigDecimal>().bean(task).name("weight").build();
            commentProperty=new JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder().bean(task).name("comment").build();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public StringProperty getNameProperty() {
        return nameProperty;
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Integer> getOrderProperty() {
        return orderProperty;
    }

    public ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> getWeightProperty() {
        return weightProperty;
    }

    public StringProperty getCommentProperty() {
        return commentProperty;
    }

}
```

BigDecimal Converter

```
public class SimpleBigDecimalStringConverter extends StringConverter<BigDecimal>{

    @Override
    public String toString(BigDecimal i) {
        if (i == null) {
            return "" ;
        } else {
            return i.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal fromString(String string) {
        if (string.trim().length() == 0) {
            return null ;
        } else {
            try {
                return new BigDecimal(string);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                return null ;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

IntegerConverter

```
public class SimpleIntegerStringConverter extends StringConverter<Integer>{

    @Override
    public String toString(Integer i) {
        if (i == null) {
            return "" ;
        } else {
            return i.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Integer fromString(String string) {
        if (string.trim().length() == 0) {
            return null ;
        } else {
            try {
                return Integer.valueOf(string);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                return null ;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Initializing code

```
Task task=new Task();
TaskAdapter adapter=new TaskAdapter(task);
nameTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(adapter.getNameProperty());
orderTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(adapter.getOrderProperty(),new SimpleIntegerStringConverter());
weightTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(adapter.getWeightProperty(),new BigDecimalStringConverter());
commentTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(adapter.getCommentProperty());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What is happening**

JavaFX Bindings use [WeakChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/WeakChangeListener.html)s behind the scenes to implement the binding. This means that the binding itself can be garbage collected if no other references to it are in scope. In your code, the `adapter` is defined as a local variable, so it gets prematurely garbage collected at some arbitrary time when the gc runs.

**Demo**

Here's a demo using your code that shows the issue. It has the same text fields you define, plus two buttons. One button dumps the value of the `task` to the console, the other forces the garbage collector to run. You'll see that the binding stops working as soon as you run the gc.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.BigDecimalStringConverter;

public class POJOBindingExample extends Application {

    private TextField nameTextField = new TextField();
    private TextField orderTextField = new TextField();
    private TextField weightTextField = new TextField();
    private TextField commentTextField = new TextField();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Task task = new Task();
        TaskAdapter adapter = new TaskAdapter(task);
        nameTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(adapter.getNameProperty());
        orderTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(adapter.getOrderProperty(),new SimpleIntegerStringConverter());
        weightTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(adapter.getWeightProperty(),new BigDecimalStringConverter());
        commentTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(adapter.getCommentProperty());

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.addRow(0, new Label("Name:"), nameTextField);
        grid.addRow(1, new Label("Order:"), orderTextField);
        grid.addRow(2, new Label("Weight:"), weightTextField);
        grid.addRow(3, new Label("Comment:"), commentTextField);

        Button showButton = new Button("Show Task");
        showButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            System.out.println(task.getName());
            System.out.println(task.getOrder());
            System.out.println(task.getWeight());
            System.out.println(task.getComment());
            System.out.println();
        });

        Button gcButton = new Button("Run GC");
        gcButton.setOnAction(e -> System.gc());

        HBox buttons = new HBox(10, showButton, gcButton);

        BorderPane.setAlignment(grid, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(buttons, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(grid, new Insets(10));
        BorderPane.setMargin(buttons, new Insets(10));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(grid, null, null, buttons, null);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Fix**

To fix the problem, you need to ensure a reference to the `TaskAdapter` persists as long as you need it. In the above code, if you move the reference to the `TaskAdapter` so that it is an instance field, everything will work as required:

```
public class POJOBindingExample extends Application {

    private TextField nameTextField = new TextField();
    private TextField orderTextField = new TextField();
    private TextField weightTextField = new TextField();
    private TextField commentTextField = new TextField();
    private TaskAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Task task = new Task();
        adapter = new TaskAdapter(task);

        // ... etc
    }
}
```

You might also be interested in reading [Tomas Mikula's blog](http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2015/02/10/val-a-better-observablevalue.html), though I don't think you can use his library directly to implement binding to a POJO.